# How to copy row and add to the same datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable and I would like to copy a row of data and insert that row of data in the same datatable. Are there way to do this? I have tried `ImportRow` and `dt.Rows.Add(dr)` but it seems both of these doesn't work.

This is part of my code:

```
    foreach(DataTable in dt.Rows){
    // my code goes here
        foreach(Datarow row in dt.Select ("email IS NOT NULL")){

          row.ImportRow(dr); 
          row.AcceptChange();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
var existingRow = dataTable.Rows[rowIndexToCopy];
newRow.ItemArray = existingRow.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be changing the iteration variable of a foreach loop, and if you do then the changes will not be reflected as you are affectively changing the data that you are iterating over and this is not good.

In your case it is I would suggest that you add your data into a new datatable, and then merge the data afterwards using the datatable.merge command.

```
            DataTable newDT = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataTable dt in myDt.Rows)
            {
                //More Code
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Select("email IS NOT NULL"))
                {
                    newDT.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            myDt.Merge(newDT);
```

Answer (score 0):

ImportRow() method will do what this question requires.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn();
idColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
idColumn.ColumnName = "id";
idColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
namesTable.Columns.Add(idColumn);

DataColumn fNameColumn = new DataColumn();
fNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
fNameColumn.ColumnName = "Fname";
fNameColumn.DefaultValue = "Fname";
namesTable.Columns.Add(fNameColumn);

DataColumn lNameColumn = new DataColumn();
lNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
lNameColumn.ColumnName = "LName";
namesTable.Columns.Add(lNameColumn);
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

// Then add the new row to the collection.
row["fName"] = "John";
row["lName"] = "Smith";
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row["fName"] = "Mohamed";
row["lName"] = "Yasin";
dt.Rows.Add(row);

foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[0] + ",  "+ item[1] + ",  " + item[2]);
}
//output:-
//0,  John,  Smith
//1,  Mohammed,  Yasin

dt.ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);
// dt.Rows[0][1] = "Peter";

foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[0] + ",  "+ item[1] + ",  " + item[2]);
}
//output:-
//0,  John,  Smith  //if modified 0,   Peter, Smith
//1,  Mohammed,  Yasin
//0,  John,  Smith
```

After import I've modified dt.Rows[0] values and checked imported new row i.e. 3rd row here is not changing as expected.